# Get Event Log Over Network with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a command that pulls an event log from another workstation on the same local network.

I currently am using the command below but it only works on the local machine I am currently logged into.

```
Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-WinLogon -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-5) -ComputerName computername
```

Is there anyway I can simply insert the [computername] and pull the log, or run the log from my workstation so I can view the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `[computername]` can be "[NetBIOS name, an Internet Protocol (IP) address, or a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of a remote computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx)". As for output file, perhaps give `Out-File` ([link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849882.aspx)) a go and use UNC path as the location.

Example:

```
Get-EventLog System -Source Microsoft-Windows-WinLogon -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-5) -ComputerName 192.168.0.10 | Out-File File-Path \\192.168.0.11\share\output.txt
```

Comment: The strange thing is that all the computers on the network have names and are registered into the Domain/Active Directory. Neither the IP or Computer Name works when I am trying to pull the log. :/

Comment: Are you local admin on those clients, and running PowerShell in the context as the same user that has local admin on those clients?

Comment: Yes I am local admin on those clients, and the user that is on the client is not a local admin.

Comment: What I meant was, are you running PowerShell (from your workstation) in the same context (ie as the same user) that's local admin on the remote client? Another thing to consider is firewall.

Comment: Yes I am and it is not working. If anything I can check with the Net Admin. 

I just wanted to see if I can pull event logs from my workstation without having to remote in and pull the log manually,
I am going to close this up now, thank you for the help!